# How can I programatically tell if R vector is list of time differences from C

Tags: r

I have a list of time differences to represent a list of durations

```
s <- c(difftime(ISOdatetime(2012,7,2,12,34,45), ISOdatetime(2012,7,2,0,0,0)),
   difftime(ISOdatetime(2012,7,2,12,34,45), ISOdatetime(2012,7,3,0,0,0)),
   difftime(ISOdatetime(2012,7,2,12,34,45), ISOdatetime(2012,7,4,0,0,0)))
```

When I run this in R I get a list of reals

```
> s <- c(difftime(ISOdatetime(2012,7,2,12,34,45), ISOdatetime(2012,7,2,0,0,0)),
+        difftime(ISOdatetime(2012,7,2,12,34,45), ISOdatetime(2012,7,3,0,0,0)),
+        difftime(ISOdatetime(2012,7,2,12,34,45), ISOdatetime(2012,7,4,0,0,0)))
> print(s)
[1]  12.579167 -11.420833  -1.475868
```

Using .Internal(inspect(s)) I see

```
> .Internal(inspect(s))
@0x0000000009c5aec8 14 REALSXP g0c3 [NAM(2)] (len=3, tl=0) 12.5792,-11.4208,-1.47587
```

However if I make a single timediff I get

```
t <- difftime(ISOdatetime(2012,7,2,12,34,45), ISOdatetime(2012,7,2,0,0,0))
```

.Internal(inspect(t))

```
> .Internal(inspect(t))
@0x000000000a108868 14 REALSXP g0c1 [OBJ,NAM(2),ATT] (len=1, tl=0) 12.5792
ATTRIB:
  @0x0000000009e27e18 02 LISTSXP g0c0 [] 
    TAG: @0x000000000323be68 01 SYMSXP g0c0 [MARK,NAM(2),LCK,gp=0x4000] "units" (has value)
    @0x000000000a104770 16 STRSXP g0c1 [NAM(2)] (len=1, tl=0)
      @0x000000000a144818 09 CHARSXP g0c1 [MARK,gp=0x61] [ASCII] [cached] "hours"
    TAG: @0x0000000000130558 01 SYMSXP g0c0 [MARK,NAM(2),LCK,gp=0x4000] "class" (has value)
    @0x000000000a1046e0 16 STRSXP g0c1 [NAM(2)] (len=1, tl=0)
      @0x00000000003aa8b0 09 CHARSXP g0c2 [MARK,gp=0x61] [ASCII] [cached] "difftime"
```

So I'm wondering if its still possible to know that you have a vector of difftime's when you look at s rather than just a vector of REALSXP

such that

```
Rf_inherit(s,"difftime")
```

would return true

Comment: `class(s)` gives `"difftime"` for me on  "R version 3.3.0 Patched (2016-05-03 r70575)" under Windows.

Comment: I can't reproduce. I see more or less the same output in both examples with R 3.3.0. In particular, `s` has the appropriate attributes.

Comment: It seems R 3.3.0 has a `c.difftime` available that does not remove attributes

Comment: class(s) in 3.1.1 produces "numberic"   (R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10) -- "Sock it to Me"), upgrading to 3.3.0 solved that issue, many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Either update to R 3.0.0, which includes a `c` method for difftimes, or use the also more efficient:

```
s <- difftime(c(ISOdatetime(2012,7,2,12,34,45),ISOdatetime(2012,7,2,12,34,45),ISOdatetime(2012,7,2,12,34,45)),
              c(ISOdatetime(2012,7,2,0,0,0), ISOdatetime(2012,7,3,0,0,0), ISOdatetime(2012,7,4,0,0,0)),
              units = "hour")
```

This constructs two vectors of POSIXct and calculates the time differences in a vectorized way (tested with R 3.2.3, for which your method fails).

Since `ISOdatetime` is also vectorized, you could also construct the POSIXct vectors more efficiently, e.g., `ISOdatetime(2012,7,2:4,0,0,0)`.